# Dependent member initialization, when reorder is not possible

Tags: c++, pointers, initialization

```
#include <iostream>
class BarParent
{
    public:
        int x;
        virtual void fuz() = 0;
};

class BarChild : public BarParent
{
    public: 
        BarChild(int new_x){x = new_x;}
        virtual void fuz(){}
};

class FooParent
{
    public:
        BarParent* p_barPar;
        FooParent (BarChild* new_p_bar)
        {
            p_barPar = new_p_bar;
            std::cout << p_barPar->x << std::endl;
        }
};

class FooChild: public FooParent
{
    public:
        BarChild barChild;
        FooChild(int new_x):FooParent(&barChild), barChild(new_x){}
};
int main()
{   
    FooChild foo(60);

    BarChild bar(99);
    FooParent fooP(&bar);
}
```

Output:

```
-548726160 
99
```

I understand why I am getting this result(undefined behavior), `barChild` is used before it is initiailized. My question is what is the 'right' to do handle this.

Comment: @zneak A simpler MWE would make users suggest to just "reorder the members."

Comment: as far as I can tell, you only needed a base class that needs to be initialized with a member field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where *design*, not *code* needs to be fixed.

By your own design:

- A `BarChild` must be constructed before `FooParent`.
- A `FooParent` must be constructed before a `FooChild`.
- A `FooChild` must be constructed before a `BarChild`.

When you want both `FooParent` and `FooChild` to refer to this same Bar object - as you're attempting in your code - design the parent class to manage it.

One example solution:

```
    FooParent (BarChild* new_p_bar)
    {
        if ( new_p_bar == NULL )
           new_p_bar = new BarChild;

        p_barPar = new_p_bar;
        std::cout << p_barPar->x << std::endl;
    }
```

Here, `FooChild` doesn't need its own instance of this object.

Comment: > By your own design:
> 
> A BarChild must be constructed before FooParent. A FooParent must be
> constructed before a FooChild. A FooChild must be constructed before a
> BarChild.

I have editted the question to reflect my intentions. I prefer not to use the heap if possible. Please advise.

Comment: @aiao You should post a new question if you have a new question.  This isn't an effective forum for back-and-forth discussions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Respect the order of initialization.

You can create a function inside BarParent to set the pointer p_barPar. Call the function in the constructor of FooChild.

Is there any reason you can't make barChild (in FooChild) a pointer as well?

Comment: yes I need `BarChild` to reside inside `FooChild`. Otherwise I would have a dirty architecture

Comment: What do you mean by a "dirty" architecture?

Comment: Your current implementation is not clean either. You have a pointer in your base class that is pointing to a member in the derived class, which is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to find another example: this one is wrong because of the RAIII principle which is not enforced: `FooParent` holds a pointer on a value which it doesn't control. An interesting example of where this setup would fail is the [slicing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty solution:

```
class FooChild: private BarChild, public FooParent
{
public:
        FooChild(int new_x): BarChild(new_x), FooParent(this) {}
};
```