# Inheritence, pointers and Software Architecture

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, architecture, member

```
#include <iostream>

class EquationOfMotion
{
    public:
        // other attributes
        virtual void findNextTimeStep() = 0;
};

class SystemModel
{
    public:
        EquationOfMotion* p_eom;
        // other atributes 
        SystemModel(EquationOfMotion* new_p_eom)
        {
            p_eom = new_p_eom;
        }
};

class VehicleEquationOfMotion: public EquationOfMotion
{
    public: 
        VehicleEquationOfMotion(...){/* initialise attribute*/}
        virtual void findNextTimeStep(){}
};

class Vehicle: public SystemModel
{
 // ???? Implementation ?????
}
```

`Vehicle` is a specialization of `SystemModel` where `p_eom` points to `VehicleEquationOfMotion`.

I would like to initialise, an instance of `VehicleEquationOfMotion` and point to it `p_eom` in `Vehicle`. I want it to be defined only within the scope of `Vehicle`, and at the same time, not to use heap. 
Is it even possible to reside `VehicleEquationOfMotion` object inside `Vehicle` without using the heap? (If not, please suggest where the *design* has gone wrong).

***Might be helpful***: I thought about the implementation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15734147/dependent-member-initialization-when-reorder-is-not-possible) question but ran into trouble (see the question).

Comment: I don't get your question.

Comment: Yes, declare a member of type `BarChild`. What exact problem are you having?

Comment: @KirilKirov clarified the question, please let me know if still not clear

Comment: @n.m. issues such as the "slicing problem"

Comment: You really need to clarify your question and give an understandable scenario of what you trying to achieve instead of using names like bar,foo,fuz..

Comment: @OopsUser added the application

Comment: There's no slicing problem unless you pass objects by value. Just don't do that. Storing objects has nothing to do with slicing.

Comment: Where is SystemModel defined?

Comment: Fix the constructor too.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, then do it like this:

```
  class FooChild : public FooParent
  {
  public:
      FooChild (int pX):m_BarChild(pX), FooParent(&m_BarChild) // point p_barPar to instance of BarChild (i.e. m_BarChild)
      {
      }
  private:
      BarChild m_BarChild; // instance of BarChild resided in the stack(not the heap) and is local to FooChild
  }
```

Comment: what about the slicing problem?

Comment: there is no slicing problem here, because your p_barPar is a pointer to BarParent not an instance, so in this, we are letting p_barPar from BarParent points to the address of m_BarChild in FooChild

Comment: slicing problem happens when we assign m_BarChild to an instance of BarParent(not pointer). for example: if p_barPar is an instance not a pointer

Comment: With this implementation, you are forced to hardcode an initialization value to m_BarChild, aren't you?

Comment: @Subway - that problem is easily modifiable by putting the m_BarChild in the initialization list, it goes first before the FooParent, check the code I've edited it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have FooParent.p_barPar to be pointing to a BarChild that resides inside FooChild, you might need to add a default ctor to FooParent and a method as follows as well: `set_p_barPar(BarChild* new_p_bar){p_barPar = new_p_bar;}`. So you get:

```
class FooParent
{
    public:
        BarParent* p_barPar;
        FooParent (){}
        FooParent (BarChild* new_p_bar)
        {
            p_barPar = new_p_bar;
            std::cout << p_barPar->x << std::endl;
        }
    protected:
        set_p_barPar(BarChild* new_p_bar)
        {
            p_barPar = new_p_bar;
        }
}
```

Then you can implement FooChild:

```
class FooChild : public FooParent
{
     public:
          FooChild(int new_x, BarChild* new_p_bar):_bar_child(new_x)
          {
               set_p_barPar(&_bar_child);
          }

     private:     //? Depends on your plans
         BarChild _bar_child();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class template.

```
class EquationOfMotion { ... };

template <typename EOM>
class SystemDynamics
{
    EOM EquationOfMotion;
    ...
};

class VehicleEquationOfMotion : public EquationOfMotion { ... };

class Vehicle : public SystemDynamics<VehicleEquationOfMotion> { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want. But the design is not safe. You are passing the pointer to a uninitialized object.

```
class Vehicle: public SystemModel
{
public:
    Vehicle(): SystemModel(&_vem)
    {

    }

    VehicleEquationOfMotion _vem;
}
```

However, it is safer to do the following:

```
class SystemModel
{
    public:
        EquationOfMotion* p_eom;
        // other atributes 
        SystemModel()
        {
        }
};

class Vehicle: public SystemModel
{
   public:
   Vehicle(): SystemModel(&_vem)
   {
      p_eom = &_vem;
   }
   VehicleEquationOfMotion _vem;
};
```